# Why does Gambit not carry heavier objects to throw as explosives?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-motivation, gambit

**Gambit**'s (*X-Men*) signature move is throwing game cards which he charges with kinetic energy, making them explode with the firepower of a hand grenade. However, the power of these explosions is often not strong enough to destroy his enemies, e.g. the giant mutant-hunting sentinel robots.

The amount of time that takes Gambit to charge an object increases with its mass. However, I think he can still find objects that are small enough to carry and charge fast, and yet heavier than cards and can unleash more powerful explosions.

Why does Gambit not carry heavier objects as additional ammunition (to the game cards) in case he needs to destroy heavier targets? (Like some infantry soldiers have an M203 grenade launcher under the barrel of their assault rifles.)

I add examples of heavier objects that Gambit can carry in addition to his cards:

- Metal objects such as shrapnel, small metal balls or nails
- Metal shurikens ("Ninja stars")
- Kunai darts
- Throwing darts
- Kitchen knives or throwing knives
- Rocks

Comment: Does the weight of the object have any relation to how much energy he can charge them with?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In the cartoon _X-Men: Evolution_ it seemed to be the case. In an episode, he charged an entire bus into blowing in the attempt of taking down a giant monster.

Comment: For the same reasons people usually carry a laptop or a phone instead of a desktop computer, because it's lightweight and you can put (some of) them in your pockets.

Comment: Yes. That's why charging paper-weight game cards yields only a hand-grenade power. If he would carry in addition heavier objects (not as many as cards) he could use them against heavier targets.

Comment: "Metal objects such as small metal balls or nails" In one episode of _X-Men: Evolution_ he picked up some bolts and nuts to throw to compensate for the lack of playing cards. It had about the same effects as when he threw the cards.

Comment: While the depiction of his powers is not always consistent, the amount of the blast seems to be a factor of how much energy he charges it with, which takes time. Larger objects seem to be able to hold more energy, but he favors charging things like cards because it's quick and easy to throw. Because he can charge just about anything, it makes little sense to carry heavier projectiles with him because the odds are good that there will be something around him that he can charge in a pinch.

Comment: How about iPods. He could throw iPods.

Comment: I feel like it's somewhat opinion based though, because we could also wonder why he's not carrying an automatic BB rifle, so that he could charge the BBs into explosive projectiles for example. Or an air rifle with steel BBs.

Comment: Easy to carry in relative bulk, aerodynamic enough to throw with accuracy, plus stylishly in theme with the roguish gambler persona he likes to project. Why wouldn't he use playing cards?

Comment: Also, for people who don't know his abilities or when he's in disguise, someone carrying a pack of playing cards will attract much less attention than someone hauling around a bag of ball bearings.

Comment: If Gambit could throw a Nokia 3310, which would be destroyed first - the Nokia or the world?

Comment: @Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI Not to mention he's almost constantly playing around with his deck of cards, shuffling it again and again; so that means he can have his projectiles in his hand, ready to throw, without arousing suspicion; by contrast, someone who carries a weapon will have everyone on alert the second they take their weapon in their hand

Answer (score 12):

According to [Gambit's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_(Marvel_Comics)#Powers_and_abilities), "The only real limitation to this ability is the time required to charge the object: the larger it is the more time it takes to charge." This was apparently described in *The Uncanny X-men #266*, although I don't have a screen grab to provide. His usual fighting style involves throwing off quick attacks, and dodging incoming ones. Heavier objects would take longer to charge, making his attacks slower, and the weight of the object would also slow him down, similar to one reasons that the average soldier doesn't carry hundreds of rounds of ammunition. In the field, he's likely to be able to find larger and heavier objects that he can charge and throw without carrying them himself.

And, honestly, some of it may come down to personal style. He likes throwing cards.

Comment: He likes playing with his cards, too.

Comment: In Uncanny x-Men #266 he doesn't throw cards, he throws barbed metal spikes. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RANwL.jpg

Comment: And in that issue there's absolutely nothing about how his powers work.

Comment: {shakes hands against the sky} WIKIPEDIA!

Comment: I know that, but I think that he could charge a metal shuriken in a time short enough to use as a weapon during combat and generate a more powerful explosion than a card.

Comment: @Triceratops: As per what I said in there, it seems the time to charge is directly correlated to the mass of the object, and the charge is correlated to the explosion power. A heavier object is going to require fighting differently in the same way that you have to change your swordfighting style with a heavier sword since you can't move it as quickly. Aerodynamics of thrown objects are generally waived in comics, but one can image that Gambit has a lot of practice in throwing cards, and knowing where they'll land.

Comment: Short answer is that maybe it would be helpful, but short of an issue where Gambit tries it and it either works or does not, it's hard to say.

Comment: Honestly, the answer may be an out-universe one: the creators didn't think of Gambit carrying few heavy throwing items as heavy ammunition, like an infantry soldier carrying a couple of grenades in addition to his assault rifle.

Comment: @Triceratops Thing is, not every soldiers carry the same weapons/tools/equipment, because each of them have a different role. You mentioned "grenades and assault rifle", but some soldiers have neither. Some of them have a DMR. In his case, Gambit is definitely not trying to be a jack-of-all-trades.

Comment: But he should have firepower strong enough to effectively overcome enemies stronger than the average FoH goon. I would like to believe Gambit's benefits and potential is more than a grenade launcher with 52 rounds.

Comment: Another thing to consider might be the accuracy/skill with which he would throw other objects. He may simply have grown up learning card tricks, not playing baseball - and as a result he can land a thrown card far more accurately than something heavier.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: "similar to one reasons that the average soldier doesn't carry hundreds of rounds of ammunition" - Uh... [standard loadout for a soldier on an active combat mission is several hundred rounds of ammunition](https://thegunzone.com/how-much-ammo-does-a-us-soldier-carry/). All that physical training is partially to make them strong enough to carry all the equipment a soldier is expected to take with them in the field.

Comment: @Triceratops Or more likely, they came up with his name and powers long before anyone thought to lay down the rules.  "You know what would be cool?   A guy that that throws cards and they explode!  How does it work?  Who cares?  It's just cool!"  Back in the day writers (and audiences) didn't care as much about the nitty gritty of how stuff actually works.

Comment: and indeed, kindof the vibe was having a diversity of people and powers, including that some of them are more and less effective in any one way, including fighting

Comment: Well, if his abilities depend on the weight, almost everything is more efficient than cards, take needles or darts.

Comment: @ShadowRanger" I stand corrected. I had thought that the standard loadout was only for a dozen or so clips, since typically the supply chain is very available.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You mean magazines*. Clips are tiny disposable metal sticks you use to insert rounds into carbines. [Examples](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbattlebornreview.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2021%2F02%2Fmagazine-vs-clip.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=73a8d353a6f3d89f4d6f943d99753c479092ba1a5332e901b50dd013fa4d4168&ipo=images)

Comment: ^_^ I stand corrected again.